# "Address Access Protected" when passing heap allocated memory through FFI in Rust

Tags: rust, ffi

I am currently attempting to use the MuJoCo physics engine with rust. Currently, I am trying to get a virtual file system, and to do so, I am using the `mj_defaultVFS` function to grab a handle to Mujoco's default virtual filesystem. In C++, this is done like this

```
auto mj_vfs = std::make_unique<mjVFS>();
mj_defaultVFS(mj_vfs.get());
```

My code to grab the default VFS looks like this in Rust.

```
let mut vfs_uninit: Box<MaybeUninit<mjVFS>> = Box::new(MaybeUninit::uninit());
mj_defaultVFS(vfs_uninit.as_mut_ptr());
let vfs = vfs_uninit.assume_init_mut();
```

Mujocos VFS is pretty large, so I want to initialize it on the heap rather than the stack to save some stack memory. However, when running this code on the rust 1.73 toolchain, I am getting the error `Signal: SIGSEGV (signal SIGSEGV: address access protected (fault address: 0x7f6efebfb000))`. I believe this is due to the way I am allocating the memory to be passed on through FFI, but I am not sure what is the "correct" way to allocate the memory.

Comment: Run it in gdb or another debugger and it should show you a stack trace when it fails. What is the signature of `mj_defaultVFS`?

Comment: what is `mjVFS`?

Comment: Are you seeing it in debug mode only or also in release mode?

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo the stack trace just shows me that it fails when calling "mj_defaultVFS"

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I am seeing the error in both modes

Comment: Are you sure this code is the culprit? I think it's inside `mj_defaultVFS` that you didn't show us.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I believe its either this code of the rust toolchain that is the subject, the code was working fine on the 1.72 toolchain but broke when I updated to 1.73

Comment: Maybe, but `Box::new(MaybeUninit::uninit())` is 99% likely to optimize in release builds. So I believe this is not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is a high chance the culprit is just a stack overflow by your big `mjVFS` struct. To call `Box::new` the struct has to be passed to it by value, and that implies it was allocated on the stack first, sometimes the compiler is able to optimize that allocation away, but not always, it's not guaranteed to, especially in debug builds.

To get around that you can allocate in place with `Box::new_uninit` if you run a nightly compiler:

```rust
#![feature(new_uninit)]
let mut vfs_uninit: Box<MaybeUninit<mjVFS>> = Box::new_uninit();
mj_defaultVFS(vfs_uninit.as_mut_ptr());
let vfs = vfs_uninit.assume_init_mut();
```

If you can't or don't want to use a nightly compiler the only way to directly allocate on the heap is currently the unsafe `alloc` API:

```rust
unsafe {
    let layout = std::alloc::Layout::new::<mjVFS>();
    let vfs_uninit = std::alloc::alloc(layout).cast::<mjVFS>();
    if vfs_uninit.is_null() {
        panic!("memory allocation of {} bytes failed", layout.size());
    }
    mj_defaultVFS(vfs_uninit);
    let vfs = Box::from_raw(vfs_uninit);
}
```

Comment: hmm im still getting the same error